# Как из списка перенести в другие списки только определённые их части?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, диаграммы

Есть следующий список:

```
a_list = [['CCCCC', 519], ['GGGGG', 724], ['DDDDD', 549], ['AAAAA', 500], ['FFFFF', 599], ['BBBBB', 510], ['EEEEE', 599]]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы его элементы были упорядочены от меньшего к большему (или наоборот), в зависимости от числа в каждом подсписке.

Например, в подсписке `['CCCCC', 555]`, число - 555.

То есть должен получиться следующий список:

```
b_list =[['AAAAA', 500],['BBBBB', 510],['CCCCC', 519],['DDDDD', 549],['EEEEE', 599]['FFFFF', 599],['GGGGG', 724]]
```

После этого хочу разделить его на два разных списка, но с тем же порядком, что и в списке `b_list`:

```
name_list = ['AAAAA','BBBBB','CCCCC','DDDDD','EEEEE','FFFFF','GGGGG']
trps_list = ['500','510','519','549','599','599','724']
```

Это необходимо, чтобы вывести с помощью модуля `matplotlib` горизонтальную столбчатую диаграмму. Если вы знаете, как сразу всё распределить в упорядоченном виде, то можете написать.

Должно получиться примерно так, но диаграмма должна быть отсортирована:

[image: ![П]

Comment: я так и не понял - должна ли быть отсортирована столбчатая диаграмма по значениям или нет ?

Comment: Да, от меньшему к большему либо наоборот.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

(pd.DataFrame(sorted(a_list, key=lambda x: x[1]), columns=["country", "value"])
   .set_index("country")
   .plot.barh(grid=True))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня ничего не высвечивается. Программа просто завершается

Comment: если вы запускаете это как скрипт, то добавьте `plt.show()` в конце

Comment: Спасибо большое!